# Continouity and norm of linear operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces, $x_0 \in X$, $\phi_0 \in Y^{'}$. Show that linear operator $\mathcal{B}(X,Y): A \to \phi_0 (Ax_0) \in \mathbb{K}$ is continuous and find its norm.

From the form of the operator I know it is continuous and its norm should be $||\phi_0|| \cdot ||x_0||$, but I need to prove it.

My attempt was:
$$|\phi_0 (Ax_0)|\le||\phi_0||\cdot||Ax||  $$
but it is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\psi(A):=\phi_0(Ax)$.

Then $ ||\psi(A)||=||\phi_0(Ax)|| \le || \phi_0||*||Ax|| \le || \phi_0||*||x||*||A||$.

This gives: $ \psi$ is bounded and $|| \psi|| \le || \phi_0||*||x||$.

Your turn.

Comment: Now I only need to show equality. I guess it would be achieved by taking identity as $A$.

Comment: there exists a vector $x_1\in X$ such that $|\phi_0(x_1)|=||\phi_0||_{Y'}$ and so $|\phi_0(||x_0||_X x_1)|=||\phi_0||_{Y'}||x_0||_{X}$ and there exists $A\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ such that $Ax_0=||x_0||_X x_1$

Comment: @PeterMelech: No, if $X$ is not reflexive, the norm of $\phi_0$ might not be attained, i.e., $|\phi_0(x)| < \|\phi_0\| \, \|x\|$ for $x \ne 0$. But there is a sequnence $\{x_n\}$ with $\phi_0(x_n) \to \|\phi_0\|$ and $\|x_n\| \equiv 1$.

Comment: I think I was wrong. To show that norm is attained I should find sequence of $A_n$, is this right?